# Sending email with codeigniter not accepting a url

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$message = $this->load->view("email_template","",true);
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('noreply@trialwelcome.com');
$this->email->to($capture_data->email);

$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);

$this->email->send();
```

This code is working perfectly when `email_template` view sends `<a href="http://google.com">CLICK</a>` but not working when it sends `<a href="http://cupohotelero.com">CLICK</a>`. It works with every URL other than this

Comment: What mail server are you using to send the emails?

Comment: That is the code I have, my server is hostgator

Comment: Check your mail logs in CPanel and see if the email is being rejected for any reason.

Comment: probably spam filters on the destination mail server

Comment: but I can manually send email